# Configure Htaccess in Laravel to serve website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have this folder structure for laravel app I uploaded it online to cpanel.

[image]

But if I access this laravel app in browser, I need to access it like this 
http://venkasure.com/venkasure/public/

where as I was expecting it to be as http://venkasure.com

I am not sure whether it's because of .htaccess settings .

My .htaccess file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I don't have much experience in configuring htaccess files, need help or do I need to add htaccess file in root.

Comment: It's not your htaccess, it's your apache config. It needs to point to public for documentroot

Comment: could you please help me in doing so , I am new to these configurations and not sure from where to start

Comment: I have no idea how your ISP is setup. Somewhere you probably have an apache virtualhost config that has a documentroot pointing to venkasure when it should point to venkasure/public. Or cpanel might have some interface for "Apache Configuration". Good luck.

Comment: In cpanel, I changed root directory of app to point to venkasure/public and it worked. Thanks